# What are the className to make responsive a site with Tailwindcss on NextJS on Turbo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, vercel

What are the className to make responsive a site with Tailwindcss on NextJS on Turbo

[image: page-limits]

Comment: What is a limit of the page?

Comment: how can I mesure it? its the problem is the data fetched is randomly longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding **break-all** in your class.

```
   <div className="w-[100px]">
    <div className="break-all"> 
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </div>
   </div>
```

this will break in the limit of the parent:

```
100px
---------
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
```